# $_POST data from iOS getting lost when calling PHP web service

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, web-services, post

I am only a beginning stage iOS developer, but I am a full time PHP developer. My iOS developer's application calls my web service over POST, but for whatever reason, my web service is not receiving the response properly.

Here is the Objective-C code that he has developed:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSData* requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[@"{\"method\":\"referrals\",
\"params\":
[{\"iv\":\"some iv value\",
\"data\":
{\"first_name\":\"pEBquIatFcWCrgEVHFhzhw==\",
\"cellular_ipv4\":\"ypMBZu80ZIeVrTpEH0daTg==\",
\"last_name\":\"353YvmRmSw9sKQ+lBrKKcg==\",
\"email\":\"tTiWcT14kuVVgmKuu7PoIw==\",
\"sent_via\":\"69JPdtxeHCAdG/cECGYg5A==\"}
}],
\"id\":\"1\"}" UTF8String] length:[reqString length]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];


if (urlConnection != nil) {
[urlConnection release];
urlConnection = nil;
}


urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
[request release];
```

As far as we can tell, it is sending the data via POST attached to the key 'referrals'. However, when my PHP web service checks the $_POST variable for the 'referrals' key, it does not find it. Here is the relevant PHP code:

```
if(array_key_exists('referrals', $_POST))
{
    //some code
}else
{
    //error response
}

// Send JSON response
//header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $message;
```

The iOS app consistently gets back the error response, which is only set if 'referrals' **does not** exist in $_POST. I've Unit Tested the PHP web service using CURL and get successful results consistently.

Where does the error lie?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` instead?

Comment: My iOS developer has gone home for the night, so I can't test that until the morning. Though I have created a script to grab the contents of the $_POST variable to examine what is being sent. But so far the data is inconclusive. Hoping that there's something glaringly obvious that we're just not seeing.

Comment: Been a while since i've done php, but does php detect the content type and automatically parse the json for you or is $_POST only for form encoded parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the PHP code was not the issue, but the method he was using to send the request over POST. I was never able to find out from him definitively what the specific issue was as he had to rewrite it several times in order to get it to work. From my understanding, the Objective-C way of sending POST data had to be tweaked.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your PHP line be this instead?

```
if(array_key_exists('method', $_POST))
```

You should debug this on the server side. For example, you could write the contents of `var_dump($_POST)` to a file.

Comment: The thing is, we've changed and tested it both ways... and no luck.

Comment: So what are the results of var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: Currently, the dump is simply `Array()`, which shows that nothing is getting through... So, I went and tested it on the external server using CURL from my local Ubuntu install... and still the same. Nothing seems to be getting to $_POST. Could this be an Apache/PHP5 setting that is misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

What URL are you trying this on? If you are running trying this on an emulator and your PHP scripts is on localhost it might not work if you try to access a url like `http://localhost/myscript.php` this is because the emulator might have it's own localhost if it is a virtual machine

In a Android emulator `http://10.0.2.2` is the address to the host machine

Comment: A response IS received... only its the response that gets sent when "if" fails and "else" is called...

Comment: @ScottTRogers what does var_dump($_POST) give you?

Comment: Currently, the dump is simply Array(), which shows that nothing is getting through... So, I went and tested it on the external server using CURL from my local Ubuntu install... and still the same. Nothing seems to be getting to $_POST. Could this be an Apache/PHP5 setting that is misconfigured?

Comment: In your POST request, what content do you have in the body? I don't believe it's the settings you have to look at

Comment: Try setting Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded and your body to referrals=Testing